# Creating a full page-width header

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't make my header run the full width of the page.

I looked through the solutions here and tried:

```
#masthead 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

This didn't work.
There are still margins on either side of the home page header: http://patrycjajadach.com

Answer (score 1):

on the div with the id="page" there's

```
padding: 0 2%
```

change it to

```
padding: 0
```

Comment: For reference, line #3263 of style.css.